# How do I set up PHP post dates with a 1and1 database and Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I'm very, very new to PHP, so please bear with me. I'd like to configure my current website (whose files I've already converted to .php, and which I work on in Dreamweaver), so that every time I upload a new file to my server, the upload date will automatically be displayed in the article (WordPress and other CMSs do this, but I don't have the time to make a WordPress template similar to my current site layout).

The problem with the database is that it's hosted at 1and1, where remote access (i.e. via Dreamweaver) isn't permitted, and I have to use phpMyAdmin at my host's website, which is ridiculously slow. Whenever I want to, for example, create a table, I have to go through a ton of slow-loading pages.

Is there any way to automate this process, at least to some degree?

Comment: There's probably not enough detail to go on here, but I'd say that if this is a custom PHP-based website (i.e. each page of content has a .php extension and you're not using Wordpress or similar) then you just need a piece of code replicated in each footer that reads the page modification time and displays it in human-readable format. 1and1 certainly _should_ support "remote access" - do you mean FTP, SFTP, SCP or rsync (etc)? Find out which mode you're using in DreamWeaver - all hosts support either FTP or SFTP.

Comment: Of course they support remote access to the server itself via FTP and sFTP, but not the DBs.

Comment: Ah, gotcha - apols. I think it was the Dreamweaver bit that threw me - I knew that it can upload files via FTP, but I didn't know it had a feature to connect to databases! OK, so Tom Walters' response makes plenty of sense now - that's what I'd do. (Incidentally it is often a good thing that databases cannot be connected to remotely - it's an additional security vector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always build a simple PHP script which connects to your database and runs an SQL query. You could then just visit the page and the query would be executed.

Here's a tutorial on writing SQL and running it with PHP if you're not sure: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Comment: I'd build on this and offer a form into which SQL scripts could be uploaded. Obviously this would need to be behind an htaccess system, and disabled when no longer needed.

Comment: Yes customising it for SQL input would be an excellent idea, and obviously get rid of it when you're done with it. And as for the error might I suggest a good old refresh?

Comment: Nope, tried it in  three browsers (Chrome, Safari and Opera), and refreshed a couple of times in each. I tried Googling the link, and it just loads indefinitely.

Comment: OK, I read the tutorial, and I've got a problem with one of the first steps. I ran the command
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
?>
in PHPMyAdmin's SQL query window, but I get an error saying that there's an SQL syntax error at line 1 (in practice, I replaced the username and password with those assigned by my host).

Comment: The code you attempted to run is PHP, so you need to make a file on your server like sql.php and put it in that, the query window in PHPMyAdmin is for SQL only, rather than PHP.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it's what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin has a "SQL" tab, where you can enter text commands just as if you were typing them into your local mysql command line. If you're not sure where to find it, there's an image in [this (otherwise irrelevant) tutorial](http://computeraxe.com/null-values-handled-nicely-with-the-php-error-suppression-operator/). You can use this to create and modify tables, and also run queries of all kinds.